# high z-index parent with low z-index children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

let me explain the situation, I got a draggable div, and whenever I start dragging, I apply some guide lines to the div.
Since i want the div to be above EVERYTHING, I set a class to the div element that contains a z-index of 20000 !important.

Happens that my guide-lines are inheriting that very same z-index, and I don't want them to be above everything as its parent div.

I got something like this:

```
<div id="parent" style="z-index: 20000 !important; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
   <div id="guide-lines">
      <div class="guide-top"></div>
      <div class="guide-left"></div>
      <div class="guide-right"></div>
      <div class="guide-bottom"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The guide lines are lines that crosses all the browser document, like to indicate its position.
But, as I said, I don't want them to be above everything.

Is there any chance to set a lower z-index? or even 0 to the guide-lines?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try a negative z-index? JSFiddle would be helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z-index is relative to the parent, so if you want a child to be below the parent, you will need to use a negative z-index.

```
z-index:-500;
```

Comment: thanks gonna try to use that and let you guys know :)

Comment: i ended up using other solution but because it was a different thing that i needed, anyway i'm going to give you the tick since that one actually works too but for other scenario :) thanks for your help!